# Como copiar un bitmap en otro bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Tengo un bitmap de 246x400 y quiero crear un bitmap de 500x500, una vez teniendo el bitmap de 500x500, quiero insertar el bitmap de 246x400 en medio del bitmap de 500x500, como así:

[image]

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
Bitmap bmp2 = bmp1.copy(bmp1.getConfig(), true);
```

Comment: Agrega el código que has  realizado o investigado. Revisar [ask].

Comment: Gracias por editar @gokuvenz , una pregunta, imagino pretendes agregarlos a ImageViews como contenedores? con esos contenedores el aspecto de la imagen puede cambiar o deseas cortar la imagen, por ejemplo si es rectangular , la imagen puede verse correctamente en el contenedor grande, pero en el de 246X400  se cortaría o trataría de mantener el aspecto?

Comment: no solo  necesito obtener esa imagen en bitmap para mandarla como string a un webservice

Comment: Esos contenedores que llamas son las imágenes bitmap, la rectangular es la que ya tengo (246x400), necesitó generar el otro(500x500), después de eso solo queda insertar el bitmap1 dentro del bitmap2, y retornar ese bitmap

Comment: Lo que quieres es fusionar ambos bitmaps para que uno quede superpuesto en el otro y retornarlo en una sola instancia tipo Bitmap?

Comment: Si para al final obtener un solo bitmap